# update instruction of the deprecated tensorflow dataset sliding window with tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tensorflow, deprecated, sliding-window

I am trying without success to update my code with the instruction given in the tensorflow documentation (api r1.13). I am using the [tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset) and the deprecated [tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/sliding_window_batch) for a RNN and all works fine (except the deprecated sliding_window warning message).

For the update I have simply replaced

```py
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch(batch_size, 1))
```

with

```py
dataset = dataset.window(size=batch_size, stride=1).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(batch_size))
```

and I got the following error for a csv file with 50 columns:

```sh
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 50 were given
```

How can I solve this problem for any csv file (with any number of columns)?